# Why did my UI Bootstrap datepicker-popup stop working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I updated to UI Bootstrap 0.11.0 and my datepickers stopped appearing as they should. I have a plunker that demonstrates it at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fxVbuTxlTetNvQW4JeZ?p=preview). Very simply, I have:

```
<input ng-model="formData.dueDate" type="text" id="dueDate" name="dueDate"
    class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy"
    datepicker-append-to-body="true">
```

The datepicker pops up correctly using UI Bootstrap 0.10.0 but not with the lastest version. I do not see any errors in the console.

This leads me to believe I was possibly using the datepicker incorrectly in the previous version or they've had a regression. Am I doing something wrong here?

Update:

I've included the answer below. Show on focus and show on click have been removed from UI Bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature was removed from UI Bootstrap. See https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2149 for more information. I have created another Plunk to demonstrate the workaround at http://plnkr.co/edit/ct46CK6NRb9FWdpzfQpI?p=preview.

Comment: This is the right answer ! And the change log is not clear about this point. Thanks.

Comment: Plunk example throws JS error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
 at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js:78:12 ...

Comment: You are right. I have edited the plunker example so that ng-focus is not used. I believe is-open was being set twice, once for ng-focus and another for ng-click. Setting them at the same time while $digest is handling the first change appears to be a problem. I do not currently fully understand how to workaround it, so I have removed the ng-focus code. Linky http://plnkr.co/edit/ct46CK6NRb9FWdpzfQpI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't the only one with the issue.  I suggest leaving your feedback on the Github project:

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2098

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I submitted an issue with the author and he got back to me.