# Angular form.$error on all input date-picker elements, "$error":{"date":true}

Tags: angularjs, validation

I would like to enable save button only when form validation returns no error. Everything works fine until I put date input field, and I have no idea what is bothering him.

This is an example of such field:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'fg-toggled': openCalendar.ppDateClosing == true }">
    <input name="dateClosing" 
           ng-click="openDatePicker($event, 'ppDateClosing')" 
           ng-model="pp.dateClosing"
           ng-readonly="true"
           placeholder="{{pp.dateClosing}}"
           is-open="openCalendar.ppDateClosing" 
           data-date-format="dd.MM.yyyy"
           datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" 
           datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
           show-weeks="false" 
           type="text">
</div>
```

If I remove the `datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"` line, then validation works ok, but date-picker doesn't.
Did anybody have similar problem or has an idea how to solve this?
(I'm using angular boostrap)

Comment: please check this [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my UI Bootstrap datepicker-popup stop working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479674/why-did-my-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-popup-stop-working)

Comment: I wouldn't say it has anything to do with this github issue or stackoverflow question. Datepicker-popup works fine, validation doesn't. I was removing line by line to try to see where it breaks, and eventually came up with the datepicker-popup line - but I need that line to have the calendar showing the date in correct format. Calendar works just fine with it. It is only when I added form validation that something "broke".